# Glassfish environment for multiple applications with common dependency

Tags: java, glassfish

I have a question which I am struggling with. The problem is that I do not even know what exactly I should search for on google, so that's why I am asking for a short explanation here on SO.

Let's say that I have three projects: A, B and C. A is a dependency for both B and C. B and C are web-services for example, which can be deployed in Glassfish. In A, there is a class with a **static** field, let's say an `int`. When building project B, the `static int` has value 3. Then, we build project C but we change the value of the `static int` to 4.

The question is: when we deploy both B and C to Glassfish, do these applications run in separate "environments" where the the `static int` has different values in each environment (3 in env of B, 4 in env of C) or is there just one `static int`?

LE: B and C are both deployed in the same Glassfish domain. Glassfish version is 3.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The problem is that I do not even know what exactly I should search for on google, so that's why I am asking for a short explanation here on SO.
```

What you want to search for is "Classloader". Objects of this type are responsible for loading Java classes. Each class loaded by JVM is identified by both its fully qualified name *AND* the instance of classloader that loaded it. This means that in a single JVM you could have a couple of classes named exactly "com.example.Test", each loaded by a different classloader - and each of them would have its own static fields. What's more, the classes would be considered different at runtime: casting "com.example.Test" from one classloader to "com.example.Test" from some other classloader would end in a ClassCastException.

To avoid situation where you have multitude of common classes loaded multiple times (like java.util.List), classloaders are usually kept in a clean hierarchy. Each classloader knows its "parent", that is classloaders responsible for loading "more general classes". When we try to load a class (which usually happens "by name"), like "com.example.OtherTest", the current classloader tries to ask its parent if it is able to load it  (and the parent in turn asks its parent, and so on). This way each class is loaded by the most general classloader that is able to load it (java.lang.String will be always loaded by the standard bootstrap classloader even if some other classloader has some different version available).

When you deploy a war, glassfish creates a separate classloader for it. The classloader knows how to load classes from WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes. Its parent is (or at least grandfather) the domain classloader, common for all applications. So before application classloader loads any class - it will ask Glassfish to do it.

The whole process is quite configurable and enables you to have just one copy of common libraries loaded into JVM (eg. if you put your libraries into - AFAIR - domain1/lib/ext, they will be available to the domain classloader, an ancestor of each application's classloader; or you could even put it in your JRE's lib/ext folder and have it available to the main classloader, that will load the classes for any application you run). In such case they will share static fields. Or you could have your libraries loaded by war classloaders, and have all the static fields "private" to your applications.

Comment: `Or you could have your libraries loaded by war classloaders, and have all the static fields "private" to your applications.` this means that if I package the dependency twice in two different `WARs`, then different class loaders will be used? (sorry for a stupid question but I just want to be sure, this problem has been bugging me for quite some time and I want to fully understand what's going on).

Comment: Yes. Each web application gets its own classloader; otherwise applications could "attack" each other.

Comment: btw: the number of times a class is loaded does not depends on number of jars. You could imagine the same class loaded ten times from the very same file, by different classloaders.

Comment: Note that the classloader order is one way in stand-alone applications and the exact opposite inside a servet container.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: I don't quite understand? afaik,  classloader structure is not really standardized for servlet containers, but all the containers I can think of work exactly the same as in stand-alone applications. Strictly speaking, servlet container IS a stand-alone application. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @fdreger It is explained at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading

Answer (score 2):

If "A for B" and "A for C" are different, you need to create a deployment for both B and C each enclosing its own copy of A.

The simplest approach is most likely a separate WAR for B enclosing A_for_B.jar and a separate WAR for C enclosing A_for_C.jar.

Comment: this is indeed the case for my scenario. sorry for not mentioning that in my initial question. they are both packaged in two different `WARs`, one with `A_B` and the other with `A_C`. does this mean that there will be two `static ints` because of the two copies of `A`?

Comment: Yes, there will exist two A's unaware of each other (in the default configuration of glassfish)